# Can I make TypeKits fonts work locally even if I'm not using a webserver (no localhost)?

Tags: typekit

I'm just playing around with an index.html file and an accompanying CSS file that I'm viewing in my web browser. How do I allow this to work with TypeKit? I know I can have it work if I have a webserver with localhost running, but in this case I don't.

Answer (score 2):

If you have some working webserver, you can configure the typekit to use that domain, upload the index.html there, and then rip the typekit CSS to use it locally. The fonts are included as data URIs.

To do that, for example, in Chrome: Open the dev tools, go to the network tab, reload the hosted page and look for a CSS file from use.typekit.net (d?abcde2134...). Then copy the data from the preview tab into a local CSS file and you're good to go.